# Array index out of bounds exception in quiz program

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having the hardest time trying to fix an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

I have a method that reads from a file line by line. If the name and id on the line matches some variables that I pass to the method then I save that line to an array.

This program simulates a quiz. The user cannot use the same name and id more than 2 times; therefore, the file only contains 2 lines with the same name and id.

I created an array named `temp` to hold those two lines from the file. If the file is empty the user takes his two tries and when he tries again it he is denied. So if you enter a different name and id you should get 2 more tries. At this point the file has two lines from the previous user, but when the new user tries he can only take the test once. When he tries the second time I get the array out of bounds exception.

My question is: Is the array `temp` holding the previous values and is that why I am getting the exception?

```
private String readFile(String id, String name) {
    String[] temp = new String[3];
    int i = 1;
    int index = 0;
    String[] split = null;
    String idCheck = null;
    String nameCheck = null;
    temp = null;

    try {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("studentInfo.txt"));
        String line = null;           

        try {
            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    split = line.split("\t\t");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                nameCheck = split[0];
                idCheck = split[1];

                if (idCheck.equals(id) && nameCheck.equals(name)) {
                    temp[index] = line;
                }

                index++;
            }
            read.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    }

    if (temp != null) {
        if (temp[1] == null) {
            return temp[0];
        }
        if (temp[1] != null && temp[2] == null) {
            return temp[1];
        }
        if (temp[2] != null) {
            return temp[2];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Need the stacktrace showing the exact exception and line number.

Comment: You'll get an IOOB exception here - `idCheck = split[1];` - if there is no double tab on the line.

Comment: `temp[index] = line;` --> This seems problematic. If your file has more than 3 lines that meet your `if` statement right above, you will end up with an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: so here is the exception:                                     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at Final.readFile(Final.java:188) line 188 is temp[index] = line; What i dont understand is the following if you use your name and your id 2 times that is it you can not use it again therefore there will be only 2 lines in the file with the same id and name so each time the method searches the file and finds a match there should only be a maximum of two lines and since the array temp has allocated 3 elements it should work right?

Answer (score 1):

I see two places where you can get an index out of bounds exception. First is this code:

```
try {
    split = line.split("\t\t");
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
nameCheck = split[0];
idCheck = split[1];
```

If the line does not have a `"\t\t"` sequence, then `split` will have only one element and trying to access `split[1]` will throw an exception. (As an aside: you shouldn't silently ignore exceptions!)

The second (and more likely source of the problem) is that you are incrementing `index` for every line that has matching id and name, so once you read the third such line, `index` is out of bounds as a subscript for `temp`.

You can either include `index < temp.length` in your `while` loop condition, or you can use an `ArrayList<String>` for `temp` instead of a `String[]`. That way you can add an unlimited number of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is what may be happening

```
    String[] split = "xxx\tyyyy".split("\t\t");
    System.out.println(split[0]);
    System.out.println(split[1]);
```

.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting `temp = null;`

The next reference to temp is:

```
if (idCheck.equals(id) && nameCheck.equals(name)) {

    temp[index] = line;
}
```

I believe you should remove the line `temp = null;`.  All it does is trash the array you just instantiated above that line.

That index makes me a touch nervous, but I suppose if you are certain that the file being read will never have more than 3 lines...